# PHP look-and-say sequence

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to code Conway look-and-say sequence in PHP.
Here is my code:

```
function look_and_say ($number) {
    $arr = str_split($number . " ");
    $target = $arr[0];
    $count = 0;
    $res = "";
    foreach($arr as $num){
        if($num == $target){
            $count++;
        }else{
            $res .= $count . $target;
            $count = 1;
            $target = $num;
        }        
    }
    return $res;
}
```

As I run the function, `look_and_say(9900)` I am getting value I expected: `2920`.
My question is for assigning  `$arr` to be `$arr = str_split($number)` rather than `$arr = str_split($number . " ")`, the result omits the very last element of the `$arr` and return `29`.

Is it normal to add empty space at the end of the `$arr` foreach to examine the last element or is there any better way to practice this code - besides regex way.

Comment: Notice that without the space, the `else` does not run for the last element. The better way would be to add `$res .= $count.$target;` after the `foreach`, before the `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 methods I was able to come up with.

1 is to add concatenate at the result after the loop too.

```
function look_and_say ($number) {
    $arr = str_split($number);
    $target = $arr[0];
    $count = 0;
    $res = "";
    foreach($arr as $num){
        if($num == $target){
            $count++;
        }else{
            $res .= $count . $target;
            $count = 1;
            $target = $num;
        }        
    }
    $res .= $count . $target;
    return $res;
}
```

And the 2nd one is to add another if clause inside the loop and determine the last iteration:

```
function look_and_say ($number) {
    $arr = str_split($number);
    $target = $arr[0];
    $count = 0;
    $res = "";
    $i=0;
    $total = count($arr);
    foreach($arr as $num){        
        if($i == ($total-1))
        {
            $count++;
            $res .= $count . $target;
        }
        elseif($num == $target){
            $count++;
        }else{
            $res .= $count . $target;
            $count = 1;
            $target = $num;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to suggest you other way using two nested `while` loops:

```
<?php

function lookAndSay($number) {
    $digits = str_split($number);
    $result = '';
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < count($digits)) {
        $lastDigit = $digits[$i];
        $count = 0;
        while ($i < count($digits) && $lastDigit === $digits[$i]) {
            $i++;
            $count++;
        }
        $result .= $count . $lastDigit;
    }

    return $result; 
}
```